# Simplifying an xPath query

Tags: xpath

Simplify the following xPath so that it is as small as possible but still identifies the element in question

```
/html/body/div[@id='vwd4_page']/div[@id='vwd4_content']/div[@id='Layout']/div[@id='FooterAction']/div[3]/form[@id='searchform']/span/input[@id='searchfield']
```

Comment: This sounds a lot like homework, but I can't imagine XPath being taught at schools... at least try something on your own, or maybe even show the HTML structure?

Comment: hmm... looks suspiciously like homework...

Comment: everything about this post could be improved.

Comment: If this is not homework, then the question is very badly put, as it sounds *exacty* like a homework/test question just pasted in.

Comment: some thing like that as I am trying to learn xpath on my own and came across this in google which was asked by some one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you use this?

```
//input[@id='searchfield']
```

Comment: Or shorter yet, `//*[@id='searchfield']` but of course that'd be a little more dependent on the markup.

Comment: as long as the `id` attributes are unique then this will work. Unfortunately that's not always the case.